# ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, ssl, gmail

I am sending a few scheduled emails via gmail, with python 2.7 on windows. A couple of days ago, I started getting this error, without having made any changes to the job, the python install or the windows server.

It is the first email of the day being sent. Subsequent emails go through just fine. When running manually it from command line in the morning, it runs just fine.

Any ideas of what could be wrong, or how to fix/workaround it are appreciated.

My method from 'mymethodsfile' look like this

```
import sys
import ast
from datetime import datetime

import smtplib
import mimetypes
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


    def send(self):
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From']=self.sender
        msg['Subject']=self.subject
        msg['To'] = ", ".join(self.recipients) # to must be array of the form ['mailsender135@gmail.com']
        #msg.preamble = "preamble goes here"
        #check if there are attachments if yes, add them
        if self.attachments:
            self.attach(msg)
        #add html body after attachments
        msg.attach(MIMEText(self.htmlbody, 'html'))
        #send
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        s.starttls()
        s.login(self.sender,self.senderpass)
        s.sendmail(self.sender, self.recipients, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
```

Error in the logs(script path and filename anonymised):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\filename.py", line 12, in <module>
    mymail.send()
  File "C:\path2\mymethodsfile.py", line 49, in send
    s.starttls()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 649, in starttls
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, keyfile, certfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```